# UITableViewCell shadow disappears after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, shadow

I have subclassed UITableViewCell class to add shadow below my cell. The shadow is added correctly, when TableView appears on screen. But, when I scroll tableview down, and cell with shadow hides above the screen, the shadow disappears.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.shouldAddShadow) {
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.5;
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        self.layer.shadowColor = [[[UIColor appDarkDividerColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9] CGColor];
        [self setClipsToBounds:NO];
        [self.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
        CGRect shadowFrame = self.layer.bounds;
        CGPathRef shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowFrame].CGPath;
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath;
    }
}
```

forgot to mention, that i have tableview with static cells; so prepareForReuse isn't called. I have outlets for my cells, so that i've also tried to set the shadow to my cell in scrollViewDidScroll: method. Even this din't help me

Comment: My guess is that when the cell is reused, `self.shouldAddShadow` may be FALSE. Where do you set that flag to TRUE/FALSE in your code?

Comment: It's probably have something to do with cell's reusing mechanism. I might suggest 2 things. First - add NSLog(@"self.shouldAddShadow = %@", self.shouldAddShadow ? @"YES" : @"NO") message after [super layoutSubviews]; to see what's going on with your flag when this happens. Second - maybe make this shadow thing a method and call it when you configure your cell?

Comment: forgot to mention, that i have tableview with static cells; so prepareForReuse isn't called. I have outlets for my cells, so that i've also tried to set the shadow to my cell in scrollViewDidScroll: method. Even this din't help me

Comment: It could be you need to force a layout using [cell setNeedsLayout] on scroll. That may be enough or you might need to call [cell layoutIfNeeded] to force the layout. You could put this call inside the delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: FWIW, I'm having the exact same prob right now and have so far been unable to resolve.

Answer (score 23):

I just encountered this problem. Finally I find the way to make it work.

It doesn't disappear(removed), it was just been hidden.

There we use a property **`zPosition`** of cell's layer.

> ***From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition):***
>
> The default value of this property is 0. Changing the value of this property changes the the front-to-back ordering of layers onscreen. This can affect the visibility of layers whose frame rectangles overlap.
>
> The value of this property is measured in points.

#### The default value is `0`. This leads top cell hides the bottom cell (say shadow). It means if you set shadow for a view to make it show in both sides and the margin before two cell is zero, only bottom shadow of the top cell will show up, the top shadow of the bottom shadow will be hidden.

#### When the cell goes out of the screen and then back, though the `zPosition` of each cell is still `0`, for those cells, bottom cell hides top cell now. The hide direction is opposite to your scroll direction. This is exactly the situation you met.

**So,**

```
cell.layer.zPosition = <#value you want#>
```

For example, I want to show shadow of the siblings, I can set `zPosition` of this cell's layer to `-1`, then shadow of both side will appear.

`zPosition` of a layer decide which cell can show in the front, and which shows in the back. Like `z-index` in CSS.

So the solution is change the zPosition property to make it work as you expected.

In addition, you should not set cell's `clipsToBounds` to `YES`. (default value is NO)